# General formula for $\dfrac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)$

Tags: derivatives

I would like to know the general formula for expressing $\dfrac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \left(\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)$ in terms of derivatives of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. I am stuck when trying to express $h^{(i)}(x)=\dfrac{\partial^i (g(x))^{-1}}{\partial x^i}$ in terms of derivatives of $g(x)$.

Attempt: Let $h(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$ and $h^{(i)}(x)=\dfrac{\partial^i h(x)}{\partial x^i}$. Then 
$$
\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)
=\frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \left(h(x)f(x)\right)
=\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{k}{i}h^{(i)}(x)f^{(k-i)}(x)
$$
How would I express $h^{(i)}(x)=\dfrac{\partial^i (g(x))^{-1}}{\partial x^i}$ in terms of derivatives of $g(x)$?

Comment: I'm confused, if $f$ and $g$ are functions of only $x$, then why partials?

Comment: I want to know the $k^{th}$ derivative of the function $f(x)/g(x)$ in terms of derivatives of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Faà di Bruno's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula):

$$
    {d^n \over dx^n}h(g(x))=\sum \frac{n!}{m_1!\,1!^{m_1}\,m_2!\,2!^{m_2}\,\cdots\,m_n!\,n!^{m_n}}\cdot h^{(m_1+\cdots+m_n)}(g(x))\cdot \prod_{j=1}^n\left(g^{(j)}(x)\right)^{m_j}
$$
and set $h(y)=\frac1y$.